# Pandas - is it possible to "rewind" read_csv with chunk= argument?

Tags: python, pandas, chunks, chunking

I am dealing with a big dataset, therefore to read it in pandas I use `read_csv` with `chunk=` option.

```
data = pd.read_csv("dataset.csv", chunksize=2e5)
```

then I operate on the chunked DataFrame in the following way

```
any_na_cols = [chunk.do_something() for chunk in data]
```

the problem is, when I want to do something else in the same way as above, I will get an empty result because I have iterated over chunked DataFrame already. Therefore I would have to call `data = pd.read_csv("dataset.csv", chunksize=2e5)` again to perform next operation.

Most likely there is no problem with that, but for some reason I feel that this approach is inelegant in some way. Isn't there a method like `data.rewind()` or something similar that would enable me to iterate through the chunks again? I could not find anything like that in the Documentation. Or maybe I am comitting some design mistake with that approach?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's a good idea to read your CSV **again** - you will double the number of IOs. It's better to "do something else" during the same iteration:

```
any_na_cols = pd.DataFrame()

for chunk in pd.read_csv("dataset.csv", chunksize=2e5)
    any_na_cols = pd.concat([any_na_cols, chunk.do_something()], ignore_index=True)
    # do something else
```

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. Still, this does not answer the original question. Is there an option to rewind?